# Beautiful Soup Python findAll returning empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape an Amazon Alexa Skill: [https://www.amazon.com/PayPal/dp/B075764QCX/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=paypal&qid=1604026451&s=digital-skills&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075764QCX)

For now, I am just trying to get the name of the skill (Paypal), but for some reason this is returning an empty list. I have looked at the website's inspect element and I know that it should give me the name so I am not sure what is going wrong. My code is below:

```
request = Request(skill_url, headers=request_headers)
response = urlopen(request)
response = response.read()
html = response.decode()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

name = soup.find_all("h1", {"class" : "a2s-title-content"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `User-Agent` and `Accept-Language` HTTP headers to prevent the server send you Captcha page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
}

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/PayPal/dp/B075764QCX/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=paypal&qid=1604026451&s=digital-skills&sr=1-1'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'lxml')
name = soup.find("h1", {"class" : "a2s-title-content"})
print(name.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
PayPal
```

Comment: thank you so much, that just solved all my problems!

Answer (score 1):

The page content is loaded with javascript, so you can't just use BeautifulSoup to scrape it. You have to use another module like [`selenium`](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/08/web-scraping-selenium-with-python/) to simulate **javascript** execution.

Here is an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

url='YOUR URL'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

page = driver.page_source
page_soup = soup(page,'html.parser')

containers = page_soup.find_all("h1", {"class" : "a2s-title-content"})
print(containers)
print(len(containers))
```

You can also use `chrome-driver` or `edge-driver` see [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/driver_requirements/)